# TFS 2017 installation (publication) of the plugin (project) for TFS

Tags: tfs

How to publish a project developed in VS 2015 for the TFS 2017 server itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to create a Team Foundation Server plugin, you can reference this article : [How to create and debug a Team Foundation Server server-side plugin](https://socialtfs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20create%20and%20debug%20a%20Team%20Foundation%20Server%20server-side%20plugin), it's similar for TFS 2017.

And this video tutorial : [Create TFS Plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWj-JU0Fu3c)

For write TFS extension, please see this article:
[Write your first extension for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node)

Comment: Thanks, very much ))